# How to update other component when change in single component

Tags: reactjs

I am creating timer component and implement with every task. So when I start my timer for a single task then other task timer will be disabled or hidden. I am trying to disable other timer component on start timer but it gives me only value for current component. So how can I update all components when I start a single timer?

DeveloperTasks.js

```
import { Mutation, Query } from "react-apollo";
import gql from "graphql-tag";
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

import TaskTimer from "./TaskTimer";
import Note from "./Note";
import getCDTime from "../util/commonfunc";

import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import List from "@material-ui/core/List";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
import CircularProgress from "@material-ui/core/CircularProgress";
import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Dialog from "@material-ui/core/Dialog";
import MuiDialogTitle from "@material-ui/core/DialogTitle";
import MuiDialogContent from "@material-ui/core/DialogContent";
import MuiDialogActions from "@material-ui/core/DialogActions";
import Popover from "@material-ui/core/Popover";

import DeleteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Delete";
import AssignmentIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Assignment";
import NotesIcon from "@material-ui/icons/EventNote";
import AssignmentInd from "@material-ui/icons/AssignmentInd";
import CheckCircleOutline from "@material-ui/icons/CheckCircleOutline";
import CheckCircle from "@material-ui/icons/CheckCircle";
import CloseIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Close";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import EditIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Edit";

import DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/date-fns";
import {
  MuiPickersUtilsProvider,
  TimePicker,
  DatePicker
} from "material-ui-pickers";
import UserList from "../components/UserList";
import emails from "../components/UserList";
import TodoInlineForm from "../components/TodoInlineForm";

const ms = require("pretty-ms");

//Kanban Quearies
export const tasksQuery = gql`
  query Developertasklist($contact_id_c: String) {
    Developertasklist(contact_id_c: $contact_id_c) {
      id
      name
      due_date
      dtask_start_time
      time_tracking_flag
      dtask_total_time
      status
    }
  }
`;
//Delete Task Mutation
export const DELETE_TODO = gql`
  mutation todo_operations($id: String, $deleted: String) {
    todo_operations(id: $id, deleted: $deleted) {
      id
    }
  }
`;
//Complete Task Mutation
const COMPLETE_TASK_OPERATIONS = gql`
  mutation todo_operations(
    $id: String
    $status: String
    $actual_due_date: String
  ) {
    todo_operations(
      id: $id
      status: $status
      actual_due_date: $actual_due_date
    ) {
      id
    }
  }
`;

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    width: "100%",
    marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
    overflowX: "auto"
  },
  icon: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
    fontSize: 20
  },
  button: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit
  },
  listroot: {
    width: "100%",
    minWidth: 900,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper
  },
  tasklist: {
    marginTop: 30
  },
  taskwidth: {
    width: "55%",
    display: "inline-flex"
  },
  timerwidth: {
    width: "25%"
  },
  width5: {
    width: "5%"
  },
  margin: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit
  },
  input: {
    display: "none"
  },
  datepadding: {
    "padding-right": "10px;",
    width: "17%"
  },
  formControl: {
    minWidth: 120
  },
  elementpadding: {
    "padding-right": "10px;"
  },
  completeIcon: {
    color: "Green"
  },
  popover: {
    pointerEvents: "none"
  },
  label: {
    display: "inline",
    padding: ".2em .6em .3em",
    "font-size": "75%",
    "font-weight": "700",
    "line-height": 1,
    color: "#fff",
    "text-align": "center",
    "white-space": "nowrap",
    "vertical-align": "baseline",
    "border-radius": ".25em"
  },
  labelcomplete: {
    "background-color": "#5cb85c"
  },
  labelprogress: {
    "background-color": "#5bc0de"
  },
  labelonhold: {
    "background-color": "#d9534f"
  },
  labelqafail: {
    "background-color": "#d9534f"
  },
  labelnotstated: {
    "background-color": "#777"
  },
  labelqa: {
    "background-color": "#337ab7"
  },
  labelqapassed: {
    "background-color": "#777"
  },
  labeldefered: {
    "background-color": "#f0ad4e"
  },
  hideelement: {
    display: "none"
  },
  showelement: {
    display: "block"
  }
});

const DialogTitle = withStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    borderBottom: `1px solid ${theme.palette.divider}`,
    margin: 0,
    padding: theme.spacing.unit * 2
  },
  closeButton: {
    position: "absolute",
    right: theme.spacing.unit,
    top: theme.spacing.unit,
    color: theme.palette.grey[500]
  }
}))(props => {
  const { children, classes, onClose } = props;
  return (
    <MuiDialogTitle disableTypography className={classes.root}>
      <Typography variant="h6">{children}</Typography>
      {onClose ? (
        <IconButton
          aria-label="Close"
          className={classes.closeButton}
          onClick={onClose}
        >
          <CloseIcon />
        </IconButton>
      ) : null}
    </MuiDialogTitle>
  );
});

const DialogContent = withStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    margin: 0,
    padding: theme.spacing.unit * 2
  }
}))(MuiDialogContent);

const DialogActions = withStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    borderTop: `1px solid ${theme.palette.divider}`,
    margin: 0,
    padding: theme.spacing.unit
  }
}))(MuiDialogActions);

class DeveloperTasks extends React.Component {
  state = {
    start_date: new Date(),
    end_date: new Date(),
    status: "",
    task: "",
    searchTerm: "",
    open: false,
    anchorEl: null,
    selectedValue: emails[1],
    openreport: false,
    openTodoForm: false,
    taskid: ""
  };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.searchUpdated = this.searchUpdated.bind(this);
  }
  handleDateChange = name => date => {
    this.setState({ [name]: date });
  };

  handleChange = name => event => {
    this.setState({ [name]: event.target.value });
  };

  handleClickOpen = name => event => {
    this.setState({
      open: true
    });
  };
  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };

  handleClickDialogOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ openreport: true });
  };

  handleDialogClose = value => {
    this.setState({ selectedValue: value, openreport: false });
  };

  searchUpdated(term) {
    this.setState({ searchTerm: term });
  }

  handlePopoverOpen = event => {
    this.setState({ anchorEl: event.currentTarget });
  };

  handlePopoverClose = () => {
    this.setState({ anchorEl: null });
  };

  handleClickTodoOpen(taskid) {
    this.setState({ taskid: taskid, openTodoForm: true });
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    this.setState({ openTodoForm: newProps.open });
  }

  render() {
    let todoinlineform = "";
    const { classes, contact_id } = this.props;

    const { anchorEl } = this.state;
    const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
    let currdatetime = getCDTime.getCurrentDateTime();
    let shownbutton = {
      display: "block"
    };
    if (
      this.state.openTodoForm &&
      this.state.openTodoForm === true &&
      this.state.taskid != ""
    ) {
      todoinlineform = (
        <TodoInlineForm
          open={this.state.openTodoForm}
          taskid={this.state.taskid}
          modaltitle="Edit Todo"
        />
      );
    }

    return contact_id === "" ? (
      ""
    ) : (
      <Query query={tasksQuery} variables={{ contact_id_c: contact_id }}>
        {({ loading, error, data: { Developertasklist } }) => {
          if (error) return <p>{error}</p>;
          if (loading) return <CircularProgress className={classes.progress} />;
          //Filter with task name
          if (this.state.task && this.state.task != "") {
            Developertasklist = Developertasklist.filter(
              developertasklist =>
                developertasklist.name
                  .toLowerCase()
                  .indexOf(this.state.task.toLowerCase()) != -1
            );
          }
          //Task status wise filter
          if (this.state.status && this.state.status != "") {
            Developertasklist = Developertasklist.filter(
              developertasklist => developertasklist.status == this.state.status
            );
          }

          //Label array for apply class on status label
          let labelcolor = [
            { status: "In Progress", class: classes.labelprogress },
            { status: "Completed", class: classes.labelcomplete },
            { status: "On Hold", class: classes.labelonhold },
            { status: "QA Fail", class: classes.labelqafail },
            { status: "Not Started", class: classes.labelnotstated },
            { status: "QA", class: classes.labelqa },
            { status: "QA Passed", class: classes.labelqapassed },
            { status: "Deferred", class: classes.labeldefered }
          ];
          return (
            <Fragment>
              <br />
              <div className={classes.tasklist}>
                <div className="picker">
                  <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
                    <DatePicker
                      label="Start Date"
                      name="start_date"
                      value={this.state.start_date}
                      format="yyyy-MM-dd"
                      onChange={this.handleDateChange("start_date")}
                      className={classes.datepadding}
                      animateYearScrolling
                    />
                    <DatePicker
                      label="End Date"
                      name="end_date"
                      value={this.state.end_date}
                      format="yyyy-MM-dd"
                      onChange={this.handleDateChange("end_date")}
                      className={classes.datepadding}
                      animateYearScrolling
                    />
                  </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
                  <Button
                    type="submit"
                    variant="contained"
                    color="primary"
                    className={classes.button}
                  >
                    Search
                  </Button>
                  <Button
                    variant="contained"
                    color="secondary"
                    className={classes.button}
                  >
                    Reset
                  </Button>
                </div>
                <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
                  <InputLabel htmlFor="status-simple">Status</InputLabel>
                  <Select
                    value={this.state.status}
                    onChange={this.handleChange("status")}
                    className={classes.elementpadding}
                    inputProps={{
                      name: "status",
                      id: "status"
                    }}
                  >
                    <MenuItem value="">
                      <em>Please Select</em>
                    </MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value="Not Started">Not Started</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value="In Progress">In Progress</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value="On Hold">On Hold</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value="Deferred">Deferred</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value="Completed">Completed</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value="QA">QA</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value="QA Passed">QA Passed</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value="QA Fail">QA Fail</MenuItem>
                  </Select>
                </FormControl>
                &nbsp;
                <TextField
                  id="standard-name"
                  label="Task"
                  className={classes.textField}
                  value={this.state.task}
                  onChange={this.handleChange("task")}
                />
              </div>

              <div className={classes.tasklist}>
                <Paper className={classes.listroot}>
                  <List className={classes.listroot}>
                    {Developertasklist.map((task, index) => {
                      let statusLabel = labelcolor.filter(
                        obj => obj.status == task.status
                      );
                      let completeStatusClass = classes.hideelement;
                      let pendingStatusClass = "";
                      let hidetimer = "";

                      if (task.status === "Completed") {
                        pendingStatusClass = classes.hideelement;
                        hidetimer = "hide";
                        completeStatusClass = "";
                      }

                      if (statusLabel.length > 0)
                        statusLabel = statusLabel[0].class;

                      return (
                        <ListItem key={index} divider="true">
                          <div className={classes.taskwidth}>
                            <Avatar>
                              <AssignmentIcon />
                            </Avatar>
                            <ListItemText
                              primary={
                                <React.Fragment>
                                  {task.name} - {task.due_date}
                                </React.Fragment>
                              }
                              secondary={
                                <React.Fragment>
                                  <Typography
                                    component="span"
                                    className={[classes.label, statusLabel]}
                                    color="textPrimary"
                                  >
                                    {task.status}
                                  </Typography>
                                </React.Fragment>
                              }
                            />
                          </div>
                          <div className={classes.timerwidth}>
                            <div>
                              <TaskTimer
                                developerlist={task}
                                hidetimer={hidetimer}
                              />
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div className={classes.width5}>
                            <EditIcon
                              onClick={event => {
                                this.handleClickTodoOpen(task.id);
                              }}
                            />
                          </div>
                          <div className={classes.width5}>
                            <Mutation mutation={COMPLETE_TASK_OPERATIONS}>
                              {(todo_operations, { loading, error }) => (
                                <CheckCircleOutline
                                  className={pendingStatusClass}
                                  aria-owns={
                                    open ? "mouse-over-popover" : undefined
                                  }
                                  aria-haspopup="true"
                                  onMouseEnter={this.handlePopoverOpen}
                                  onMouseLeave={this.handlePopoverClose}
                                  onClick={event => {
                                    todo_operations({
                                      variables: {
                                        id: task.id,
                                        actual_due_date: currdatetime,
                                        status: "Completed"
                                      }
                                    });
                                  }}
                                />
                              )}
                            </Mutation>
                            <Popover
                              id="mouse-over-popover"
                              className={classes.popover}
                              classes={{
                                paper: classes.paper
                              }}
                              open={open}
                              anchorEl={anchorEl}
                              anchorOrigin={{
                                vertical: "bottom",
                                horizontal: "left"
                              }}
                              transformOrigin={{
                                vertical: "top",
                                horizontal: "left"
                              }}
                              onClose={this.handlePopoverClose}
                              disableRestoreFocus
                            >
                              <Typography>Mark as completed.</Typography>
                            </Popover>
                            <CheckCircle
                              className={[
                                classes.completeIcon,
                                completeStatusClass
                              ]}
                            />
                          </div>
                          <div className={classes.width5}>
                            <div className={pendingStatusClass}>
                              {/* <Typography variant="subtitle1">
                                Selected: {this.state.selectedValue}
                              </Typography> */}
                              <AssignmentInd
                                onClick={this.handleClickDialogOpen}
                              />
                              <UserList
                                selectedValue={this.state.selectedValue}
                                open={this.state.openreport}
                                onClose={this.handleDialogClose}
                              />
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div className={classes.width5}>
                            <NotesIcon onClick={this.handleClickOpen()} />
                            <Dialog
                              onClose={this.handleClose}
                              aria-labelledby="customized-dialog-title"
                              open={this.state.open}
                            >
                              <DialogTitle
                                id="customized-dialog-title"
                                onClose={this.handleClose}
                              >
                                Notes
                              </DialogTitle>
                              <DialogContent>
                                <Note />
                              </DialogContent>
                            </Dialog>
                          </div>
                          <div className={classes.width5}>
                            <Mutation mutation={DELETE_TODO}>
                              {(todo_operations, { loading, error }) => (
                                <DeleteIcon
                                  aria-label="Delete"
                                  onClick={event => {
                                    todo_operations({
                                      variables: {
                                        id: task.id,
                                        deleted: "1"
                                      }
                                    });
                                  }}
                                />
                              )}
                            </Mutation>
                          </div>
                        </ListItem>
                      );
                    })}
                  </List>
                </Paper>
              </div>
              {todoinlineform}
            </Fragment>
          );
        }}
      </Query>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(DeveloperTasks);
```

TaskTimer.js

```
import { Mutation, Query } from "react-apollo";
import gql from "graphql-tag";
const React = require("react");
const ms = require("pretty-ms");
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import StartIcon from "@material-ui/icons/PlayCircleFilled";
import StopIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Stop";
import getCDTime from "../util/commonfunc";

//Start timer mutation
const TODO_OPERATIONS = gql`
  mutation todo_operations(
    $id: String
    $status: String
    $dtask_start_time: String
    $time_tracking_flag: String
    $developer_daily_hours: String
    $is_task_started: String
    $actual_start_date: String
  ) {
    todo_operations(
      id: $id
      status: $status
      dtask_start_time: $dtask_start_time
      time_tracking_flag: $time_tracking_flag
      developer_daily_hours: $developer_daily_hours
      is_task_started: $is_task_started
      actual_start_date: $actual_start_date
    ) {
      id
    }
  }
`;
//Stop timer mutation
const STOP_TIMER = gql`
  mutation todo_operations(
    $id: String
    $dtask_stop_time: String
    $dtask_total_time: String
    $time_tracking_flag: String
  ) {
    todo_operations(
      id: $id
      dtask_stop_time: $dtask_stop_time
      dtask_total_time: $dtask_total_time
      time_tracking_flag: $time_tracking_flag
    ) {
      id
    }
  }
`;

const styles = theme => ({
  button: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit
  },
  stopbutton: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
    color: "Red"
  },
  input: {
    display: "none"
  },
  clock: {
    color: "Green",
    fontWeight: "700",
    fontSize: "15px"
  },
  hideelement: {
    display: "none"
  },
  timerClass: {
    display: "none"
  }
});

class TaskTimer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    const total_time = !props.developerlist.dtask_total_time
      ? parseInt(0)
      : parseInt(props.developerlist.dtask_total_time);

    let statetime = total_time;
    let stateison = false;
    super(props);

    if (props.developerlist.time_tracking_flag === "yes") {
      let currentdatetime = new Date(getCDTime.getCurrentDateTime());
      let start_time = new Date(props.developerlist.dtask_start_time);
      let time_diff = Math.abs(currentdatetime - start_time) / 1000;

      statetime = time_diff + total_time;

      stateison = true;
      this.state = {
        time: statetime,
        isOn: stateison
      };
      this.startTimer();
    }
    this.state = {
      time: statetime,
      isOn: stateison,
      timerClass: "test"
    };

    this.startTimer = this.startTimer.bind(this);
    this.stopTimer = this.stopTimer.bind(this);
  }

  startTimer(next) {
    this.setState({
      isOn: true,
      time: this.state.time,
      timerClass: "abc"
    });

    this.timer = setInterval(
      () =>
        this.setState({
          time: parseInt(this.state.time + 1)
        }),
      1000
    );
  }
  stopTimer() {
    this.state.time = parseInt(this.state.time);
    this.setState({ isOn: false });
    clearInterval(this.timer);
  }

  render() {
    let totalTaskTime = parseInt(this.state.time) * 1000;
    const { classes, theme } = this.props;
    let hideTimerClass =
      this.props.hidetimer === "hide" ? classes.hideelement : "";
    let currdatetime = getCDTime.getCurrentDateTime();
    let start =
      (this.state.time == 0 || this.state.time > 0) && this.state.isOn == 0 ? (
        <Mutation mutation={TODO_OPERATIONS}>
          {(todo_operations, { loading, error }) => (
            <StartIcon
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              className={[
                classes.button,
                hideTimerClass,
                this.state.timerClass
              ]}
              //className={this.state.timerClass}
              onClick={event => {
                this.startTimer();
                todo_operations({
                  variables: {
                    id: this.props.developerlist.id,
                    status: "In Progress",
                    dtask_start_time: currdatetime,
                    time_tracking_flag: "yes",
                    developer_daily_hours: dailyhours,
                    is_task_started: "yes",
                    actual_start_date: currdatetime
                  }
                });
              }}
            />
          )}
        </Mutation>
      ) : null;

    let stop =
      this.state.isOn && this.state.isOn == 1 ? (
        <Mutation mutation={STOP_TIMER}>
          {(todo_operations, { loading, error }) => (
            <StopIcon
              variant="contained"
              className={[classes.stopbutton, hideTimerClass]}
              disabled={true}
              onClick={event => {
                this.stopTimer();
                todo_operations({
                  variables: {
                    id: this.props.developerlist.id,
                    dtask_stop_time: currdatetime,
                    dtask_total_time: this.state.time,
                    time_tracking_flag: "stop"
                  }
                });
              }}
            />
          )}
        </Mutation>
      ) : null;

    return (
      <div>
        <div className={classes.clock}>{ms(totalTaskTime)}</div>
        {start}
        {stop}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(TaskTimer);
```

Answer (score 0):

if I'm understanding your problem correctly you are trying to cause an update in sister components when a certain event happens.

I believe that the best way to do this would be to have a state in your parent component (DeveloperTasks) that holds whether or not each timer should be disabled. Then pass a callback into each timer that would update the disabled list in the way that you're looking for.

The way I'm imagining such a callback would work is:

```
function getDisableOtherTimersCallback(timerNum) {
    return timerNum => {
       return this.state.setState({disabledList: disabledList.map((value, index) => index == timerNum)})
        // this line just goes through and makes sure that the index corresponding to timerNum is the only one that's true
    }; 
}
```

Then when you render your component for timer n you would pass in the timer you get for timer n.

```
<TaskTimer
       developerlist={task}
       hidetimer={this.state.disabledList[n]}
       disableOtherTimersCallback={getDisableOtherTimersCallback(n)}
       />
```

Then whenever you want to disable the other timers you would call this method and your done!

(Also note that you can now use the disabledList to show or hide each timer!)

(Also also note that you need to add the disabledList to your state and initiate it in the way you are looking for)

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is not working because tasktimer is different component. My timer render from component only.